# GitLab CE Docker - /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb does not work as expected

Tags: docker, gitlab

I installed the GitLab CE Docker image per [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html). I'm running HTTP on a non-standard port while I experiment with it and ran into some strange problems trying to configure a different HTTP IP & port.

Per the instructions, I mapped the port with this section of the `docker run` command `--publish 192.168.88.135:8083:80` (note this machine has multiple IPs so I want to map to 192.168.88.135 specifically).

Once the container is running I connect to a shell inside it and edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#configure-gitlab) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html#expose-gitlab-on-different-ports), to

```
external_url "http://192.168.88.135:8083"
```

To reconfigure GitLab I then restart the container via `docker restart gitlab`. Once this is done I point my browser to http://192.168.88.135:8083, however the site is unreachable.

If I run `docker inspect gitlab`, sure enough the port is mapped as expected

```
"80/tcp": [
    {
        "HostIp": "192.168.88.135",
        "HostPort": "8083"
    }
]
```

What's really strange is, if I recreate the volume and container from scratch and **don't touch** `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, I can access GitLab via http://192.168.88.135:8083. Any idea what's going on? I'm leery to move my repositories to this setup until I understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation seems to be wrong as discussed [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-docker-not-working-if-external-url-is-set/4110/3). If you want to run Gitlab in port 8083 you have to change the external_url configuration option in gitlab config.rb file and you have to set the publish option in your docker run like this: `--publish 192.168.88.135:8083:8083`.

I've tried to do what you want using port 8081 using the following docker run command in just one step:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.example.com \
    --publish 192.168.1.50:8081:8081 \
    --publish 192.168.1.50:2222:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.example.com:8081/'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;" \
    --volume ~/Docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume ~/Docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume ~/Docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

After a couple of minutes you should see Gitlab running (it takes some time to populate the database and other bootstrap stuff).
[image: gitlab running]

If you are not patient you may also see a 502, but that does only mean that gitlab is starting :)

Comment: It looks like that `--env` flag was the magic touch. Following the prescribed method on the documentation, when I go in and change the `external_url` setting and restart, the container goes into a reboot loop as it fails to migrate a non-existent database (also fairly concerning LOL!).